# Way to mark Nuget-Package als Deprecated in a local repository

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuget-spec

I´ve seen that there is a way to mark packages as deprecated on nuget.org (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-packages-on-nuget-org/).

Unfortunally I don't push my packages to nuget.org but to an internal file repository. So my question is:
**Is there a way to mark a local package as deprecated (e.g. by editing the nuspec-definition or putting a file in my folder structure?**

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to do this as well, and mark a package as vulnerable.